# Excel Sequential numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in excel with rows having same Order ID grouped together. I would like to put another column with sequential numbers but fill the same number in the rows that have the same data (eg Order ID). Is there an easy way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thank you. Office 365 so I believe its latest verdion.

Comment: Ok then my answer with XLOOKUP should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports dynamic arrays, you can use this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,UNIQUE($A$2:$A$11),SEQUENCE(COUNT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$11))))
```

[image]

In other words, look for the position of the Order ID on the current row in the array of items defined by the unique list of Order IDs from column A.

Then, create an array of integers whose array length is the the same as count of unique items from column A, and return from that array of integers the integer at the same position returned previously.

Comment: Will this also put a unique number if Order ID is duplicated in next month?

Comment: It will assign a sequential number to each order ID. If you want the numbering to be month-dependent, it will be slightly different. Do you need that?

Comment: Yes Please.. basically if the Order ID is duplicated down the road I do not want to assign the same #.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, It didn't work for me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula and the data is sorted in that the Order ID are grouped:

```
=IF(B1<>B2,MAX($H$1:H1)+1,H1)
```

And copy down the dataset.